# Give rights to Azure DevOps build-in Users

Tags: azure, azure-devops, acl, azure-devops-rest-api

I was googling around all day but I can't find a solution. In Azure DevOps there are build-in Users created for each project. One of those users is a default build agent user (normally named `<projectName> Build Service`).

I already automated the creation of repositories an pipelines using the Azure DevOps REST API. The next step would be to grant certain rights to the build-in Build Agent User. I am already struggling to find the build-in user in the API.

So how would one grant rights to this user using the REST API?

The goal would be to add the default build-in build agent user to the contributer role so he can push tags to repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Give rights to Azure DevOps build-in Users

You could use REST API [Users - List API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0): to get the identifier of your group.

```
        "subjectKind": "user",
        "domain": "Build",
        "principalName": "f0a50df8-5a11-41c3-8d7e-22180f923c80",
        "mailAddress": "",
        "origin": "vsts",
        "originId": "64b9d209-XXXXX-bb46ade01dc",
        "displayName": "MyTestProject Build Service (YourOrganizationName)",
```

The `originId` is the Id in below REST API URL.

Then we use the `Identities` api.

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/Identities/{id}?queryMembership=None
```

Then get the descriptor from the json response `.Descriptor.Identifier`:

```
{
    "Id": "64b9d209-0deb-4d9c-9e8d-6bb46ade01dc",
    "Descriptor": {
        "IdentityType": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ServiceIdentity",
        "Identifier": "0a2bf5f-XXXXd-1e9006e97c76:Build:f0a50df8-5a11-41c3-8d7e-22180f923c80"
    },
```

If you don't have the group id, but have the display name:

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/Identities?searchFactor=DisplayName&factorValue={display name url encoded}&options=None&queryMembership=None
```

Then get the descriptor from the json response `[0].Descriptor.Identifier`.

Now, we have the `Identity`, we could use the REST API [Access Control Entries - Set Access Control Entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/access-control-entries/set-access-control-entries?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to set the permission for that group:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/accesscontrolentries/{securityNamespaceId}?api-version=5.0
```

Request body:

```
{ 
   "token":"repoV2/{projectId}/{repoId}/",
   "merge":true,
   "accessControlEntries":[ 
      { 
         "descriptor":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;{groupIdentifier}",
         "allow":2,
         "deny":0,
         "extendedInfo":{ 
            "effectiveAllow":2,
            "effectiveDeny":0,
            "inheritedAllow":2,
            "inheritedDeny":0
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Note the id in the url is hardcoded because its a constant. But you can also fetch from the response of

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/securitynamespaces
```

Comment: Thank you. My problem was that the project scope Build Service (org) user and the Project Collection Build Service (org) user did not pop up in the users api BUT they did in the identities api with your suggested query. From there it was easy going.

Comment: Btw in your identities query the parameters are searchFilter and filterValue rather than _factor_ ... Would you please fix this in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can get him with [Users - List API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

In the response I can see:

[image]

[image]